# Testing Restify Route Handler that contains Promise Code Block, using SinonJs and Mocha

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, sinon, restify

I have a restify action code block below:

```js
function retriveAll(req, res, next) {
        db.user
        .find({where: {id: 1})
        .then(function(user){
            res.send(user);
        })
        .catch(function(details){
            res.send(details.message);
        })
        .finally(function(){
            next();
        });
    }
```

**I want to test this action specifically validating that res.send() was called within this code block**. And later on validating the res.send() returned data. I'm using **SinonJs** and **Mocha** for testing framework. Here's a sample test code block for the method above.

```js
describe('retrieveAll()', function() {

    reqStub = {};
    resStub = {send: sinon.stub()};
    nextStub = sinon.stub();

    beforeEach(function() {
        module.retrieveAll(reqStub, resStub, nextStub);
    });

    // this doesn't work
    // and the sub.calledCount is 0
    // i wonder if it's because the res.send() is inside a Promise code block???
    // if I move the res.send() out from Promise, just before next(), then it works
    it('should call res.send()', function() {
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(resStub.send);
    });

    // this one works
    it('should call next', function() {
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(nextStub);
    });
});
```

Could someone shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `beforeEach()`'s callback function receives a `done` parameter that can be called to signal an asynchronous completion. Since your `retriveAll` function calls the last parameter (`next`) as the last action, you can pass that parameter as the `next` value and it should work:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    module.retrieveAll(reqStub, resStub, done);
});
```

You will however loose the `nextStub`, so... alternatively, you could *spy* on that `done` function:

```
describe('retrieveAll()', function() {

    var reqStub = {};
    var resStub = {send: sinon.stub()};
    var nextSpy;

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        nextSpy = sinon.spy(done);
        module.retrieveAll(reqStub, resStub, done);
    });

    // this doesn't work
    // and the sub.calledCount is 0
    // i wonder if it's because the res.send() is inside a Promise code block???
    // if I move the res.send() out from Promise, just before next(), then it works
    it('should call res.send()', function() {
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(resStub.send);
    });

    // this one works
    it('should call next', function() {
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(nextSpy);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for @Amit for the reply. I have applied your suggestion, unfortunately it still giving same error.


`AssertError: expected stub to be called once but was called 0 times`

Comment: Ohh yeah.. .just noticed, don't you mean `sinon.assert.calledOnce(re` **S** `Stub.send);`?

Comment: Also, `nextStub` test was affected and now giving same error.

Comment: That last comment isn't clear. What's your current status?

Comment: I modify my question to reflect the correction, tried it again but no luck.

Current status:  `sinon.assert.calledOnce(nextSpy);` also now giving error or failing.

Comment: Yes you're right... I misread your code to think `next` was being called asynchronously as well. Can you modify `retreiveAll` to do that, or is that not an option?

Comment: based on restify documentation the `next()` callback should be called always in each code block for the next callback chain to be called.

Comment: Yes, but it can also be called AFTER all other processing is done (it actually makes more sense to do so). Right now you're calling it synchronously, so it is executed before the then/catch handlers

Comment: you're right! I should've put `next` callback to the promise chain, under `finally` callback. It now seems to get the checking correctly for the `res.send` but the check for `nextSpy` is failing, but at least there's a progress.

Answer (score 1):

So, I got this working thanks for **@Amit** for pointing me to the `done` callback on `beforeEach`

**First**, I modified the `retrieveAll` so the `next` callback is included in the promise chain. I put it in the `finally` handler making sure that `next` will be called after all process.

**Second**, I passed the `done` to `beforeEach` and then `nextStub` will spy on `done` callback.

**Third**, instead of passing `done` cb to `module.v1.retrieveAll` I used `nextStub`. This solve the issue on testing `nextStub.calledOnce`.

The updated code now looks:

```
function retriveAll(req, res, next) {
        db.user
        .find({where: {id: 1})
        .then(function(user){
            res.send(user);
        })
        .catch(function(details){
            res.send(details.message);
        })
        .finally(function(){
            next();
        });
    }
```

```js
describe('retrieveAll()', function() {

    var reqStub = {};
    var resStub = {send: sinon.stub()};
    var nextStub;

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        nextStub = sinon.spy(done);
        module.retrieveAll(reqStub, resStub, nextStub);
    });

    // this doesn't work
    // and the sub.calledCount is 0
    // i wonder if it's because the res.send() is inside a Promise code block???
    // if I move the res.send() out from Promise, just before next(), then it works
    it('should call res.send()', function() {
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(resStub.send);
    });

    // this one works
    it('should call next', function() {
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(nextStub);
    });
});
```

I going to choose @Amit answer as best answer since he helped and gave me clues on the changes.

Comment: Looks like the test is exactly like in my answer (except for the typo you have, either `nextStub` or `nextSpy`, but yours has both), and the `retriveAll` is according to what's on my comments, is that right, or was there anything else in the end?

Comment: @amit, I've corrected it re `nextStub` and `nextSpy`.  yes,  this is same as your answers just some changes to fix the `nextStub` issue. This answer is to show what are the modifications on my original code. tnx

Comment: Cool. glad to have helped.