# Unit test handler that contains promise

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, mocha.js, sinon

I have TDD knowledge, and I've been trying to start a project in javascript applying the same principles.

I am building an API that, once hit, fires a request to an external service in order to gather some data, and once retrieved, parses it and returns the response.

So far, I've been unlucky with my saga, I've searched a lot and the most similar issue on SO I've found is this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340667/testing-restify-route-handler-that-contains-promise-code-block-using-sinonjs-an). But I've had no success in order to apply the same solution.

My implementation on the implementation side is as follows:

```
//... other handlers
weather(request, response) {
    //... some setup and other calls
    this.externalService.get(externalURL)
        .then(serviceResponse => {
            this.externalResponseParser.parse(serviceResponse)
        });
    //... some more code
}
```

And on the test side:

```
let requester;
let mockParser;
let handler;
let promiseResolve;
let promiseReject;

beforeEach(function () {
    requester = new externalRequesterService();
    mockParser = sinon.createStubInstance(...);

    handler = new someHandler({
        externalService: requester,
        externalResponseParser: mockParser
    });
});

it('returns data', function () {
    sinon.stub(requester, 'get').callsFake((url) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // so I can be able to handle when the promise gets resolved
            promiseResolve = resolve;
            promiseReject = reject;
        });
    });

    handler.weather(request, response);

    // assertions of what happens before externalService.get gets called - all green

    promiseResolve(expectedServiceResponse);

    assert.ok(mockExternalResponseParser.parse.calledOnce, 'Expected externalResponseParser.parse to have been called once');
});
```

In the last line of the test, it fails, even though I am calling what I am supposed to.
At some point I've added some logging, and I was able to see that the code of the `then` block, seems to get executed after the assertion in the test, which might be source of the problem.

I've tried to find out if there is some sort of `eventually` that could be used, so my assertion after resolving the promise would be something like:

```
assert.eventually(mockExternalResponseParser.parse.calledOnce, 'Expected externalResponseParser.parse to eventually be called once');
```

but no luck.

Does anyone have some clear explanation of what is missing? Many thanks in advance

**P.S.**- As per request, please find a stripped down version of my code [here](https://github.com/edisonspencer/js-help). Just run `npm install`, followed by `npm test` in order to get the same output.

Comment: how are getting `response` and `request` in `handler.weather(request, response);`?
also if you can provide code sandbox I could help

Comment: Hi @SakhiMansoor, I've updated my question with a link to a github repository where I get the same error. I've stripped it down, but I think all the crucial elements are there, since I still get the same output. Hope it helps. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the time spent.

I ended up finding this very good article on [Medium](https://medium.com/@54m/promises-in-express-js-apis-testing-dd0243163d57) which allowed me to solve my issue. It has a very nice explanation moving from callbacks to promises, which was exactly the scenario I had in hands.

I have updated the [github](https://github.com/edisonspencer/js-help) repository I created on how to fix it.

If you want to **TL;DR** here goes just the highlight of the changes. Implementation side:

```
async weather(request, response) {
    //...

    let serviceResponse = await this.requesterService.get(weatherURL);

    //...
};
```

And on the test side:

```
it('returns weather on success', async function () {
    sinon.stub(requester, 'get').callsFake((_) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
            resolve(expectedServiceResponse);
        });
    });

    await handler.weather(request, response);

    //...
    assert.ok(mockWeatherParser.parseWeather.calledOnce, 'Expected WeatherParser.parseWeather to have been called once'); // no longer fails here
    //...
});
```

Now keep in mind in this example, it is still synchronous. However, I evolved my API already step by step, and after migrating to this synchronous version using Promises, it was way more easier to migrate to an async version. Both in terms of testing and implementation.

If you have the same issue and need help or have questions, let me know. I'll be happy to help.